# What are effective champions to use in a double AD comp?

Tags: league-of-legends

Today, I started learning AD Kayle top lane, and became excited about double AD comps.  However, I don't really know how to get the other roles to co-ordinate with it well.  I know that a support Nunu can be quite fun for the second role.  That attack speed buff is awesome, not to mention that zone control his ultimate can add if the other team decides to dive you.

After that, I'm not really sure.  I think Janna could be great as well for peeling and chasing.  But I'm not sure for mid lane and jungle.  I'm thinking they need to be thicker to make up for the lost HP top.  Or maybe some AOE CC's could be great (eg. Malph or Galio).  Could anyone give some suggestions on the other lanes that can co-ordinate better with having two range ADs?

Comment: Hey, thunderingice, welcome to Arqade!  I've edited your question and previous answer to be much more readable.  The reason you're probably getting downvotes is because we want proper punctuation, grammar, and spelling.  If you put effort into those things, you'll have a much easier time of qualifying for the contest!

Answer (score 2):

Anivia and nautilus perhaps? Should work pretty well.

Anivia provides with a lot of utility and CC, meaning the AD will have time to damage the opponents and be safe, Nautilus is very tanky and filled with CC to protect the AD's, combined with Kayles ult you have one unreachable AD.

When late game comes and your ADs start to hurt, all you want to do is to give them time and space to damage the opponents, and you want them to live, so Nautilus provides 4 CCs and Anivia is like heaven for an AD, she can split a team up with a wall, slow an entire team and stun. This makes it really hard for the enemies to reach you, and even if they do, you have Kayle ulti to save you.

Comment: Why would it work well? Good answers to questions like this, where the answer can be somewhat subjective, are generally expected to back up their assertions with an explanation of their reasoning.

Comment: That's a great start!  Any chance you might be able to add a bit more detail?

Comment: Well, when late game comes and your ADs start to hurt, all you want to do is to give them time and space to damage the opponents, and you want them to live, so Nautilus provides 4 CCs and Anivia is like heaven for an AD, she can split a team up with a wall, slow an entire team and stun. This makes it really hard for the enemies to reach you, and even if they do, you have Kayle ulti to save you.

Comment: Älgen - that's great info! I'm going to go ahead and edit that into the main body of your answer. More info in the comments are great, but it can't hurt to put it back in your main answer either!

Answer (score 1):

Before you run a double AD comp, make sure to ban champions that could counter it. Good bans would be: Malphite, Irelia, Vlad, Leblanc, Olaf, Tryndamere, Renekton, Jarvan, Riven, etc.

Double AD comps also need someone to peel for the ADs. Good peelers are Alistar, Nautilus, Janna, Anivia, Blitzcrank, Nunu, etc.

AD carries that do well in a solo lane are: Ezreal, Vayne, Corki, Graves, and Tristana.

The AP champion that you pick should have utility to support the AD carries (Anivia, Gragas, Cassiopeia, Vladimir, Twisted Fate, etc.